# Which python code will be included in the Dask graph

Tags: graph, dask

Which python code written in the client side of #dask is really added to the task graph?

In this script for example, I am reading an hdf5 dataset of 4 dim, using a loop for the fourth dimension.
I calculate the sum for each dim called here ***g*** for generation and subtract the result of this generation and the one before it.
Then i am calling the deriv.visualize() to see how it generates the graph.

```py
alive = []
derivate = []
board = []

deriv = 0 
rest_1 = 0

hf5 = h5py.File('Datata.h5', 'r')
hds5 = hf5.get('dataset')
list(hf5.keys())
last_gen = hds5.attrs.get('last_gen')

for g in range(0,generations):

    board = hds5[g]
    arr = da.asarray(board, chunks=(4,5,4))
    res = arr.sum()
    if g!=0 :
        deriv = res - rest_1
    rest_1 = res
    
deriv.visualize()
```

[Here is the graph i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/law0Q.png)

- Here without calling .compute() the subtract operator is added to the dask graph apparently, how do we explain this ?
- If i add a .compute() in the "res = arr.sum().compute()" and keep the rest as it is, where the subtraction will be executed ? in the client side or in one of the workers ?
- An other question which is more general, if i wanna keep the partial sums in the workers, and perform the subtraction (on partial sum of the current and last generation) in the workers, is there a way to say that i want theses operations to be performed on the same chunks over different generations? (for example the worker 0 will operate always on the 3 first rows of each generation, like in mpi even if it's not the same thing at all)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dask does not look at your Python code, and so can not see anything other than what you give to it.  In this case it is these two lines:

```py
    arr = da.asarray(x, chunks=(4,5,4))
    res = arr.sum().compute()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah i have understand this, and i have updated my post to be more specific, and asked my question differently if you don't mind to recheck it